# Elliptical cross section fuselage

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a380, fuselage

Could someone help me understand the mathematics involved in Elliptical cross section fuselage that are used in A380. Also how double bubble cross sections are calculated.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Pressure? Aerodynamics? Cargo volume?

Comment: Related: [Could some one explain me with the mathematical relations on how the double bubble fuselage cross section (example A380) is designed?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/could-some-one-explain-me-with-the-mathematical-relations-on-how-the-double-bubb) and [Why is the fuselage on an airliner circular-shaped?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21523/why-is-the-fuselage-on-an-airliner-circular-shaped/21526#21526)

Comment: It seems that you've [posted this question before](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32309/62) and it was closed as "unclear what you're asking". Rather than ask the same question again, please think about how you can edit your original question to explain it better and be more specific; that will help you to get a better response.